# Reload page if click to same path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

:)

I'm trying to reload browser (with `location.reload();`) if user click in `<Link>` for the the same path, where it already.

Example:

I have a menu:

`- Home
- Contact
- About`

When user click in 'Contact', he go to '/contact'. But I he already in '/contact' and click in 'Contact' in menu, the page reload.

It's possible to do this?

What I'm trying:

```
<Link onClick={this.handleClick} to="contact">Contact</link>

handleClick(){
    var currentRoute = 'React-Route path';
    var linkRoute = 'link path';

    if (currentRoute === linkRoute)
        location.reload();
    } else {
        //do default transition
    }
}
```

But I don't figure what I need to declare in 'currentRoute' and 'linkRoute'. :(

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't reload the page. Thats a really bad idea. Instead disable the link like this:

if you are on the home page your links would look like this

```
<a href="/home" data-disabled="true">home</a>
<a href="/contact" data-disabled="false">contact</a>
<a href="/about" data-disabled="false">about</a>
```

Then in your `handleClick()` function you can just do this.

```
handleClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var disabled = $(e.currentTarget).data('disabled');
    if (!disabled){ 
        //do redirect
    }
}
```

**Basically** have a data attribute on the link that specifies if it is disabled or not (only disabled if its on the current page) and then only redirect if its on a different page

Reloading the page on the exact same page will cause you to lose all state and process that the user has done, which doesn't need to happen. It also reduces traffic on your server for a new page load (aka any data you need to load on the page load you don't have to do again).

Comment: But my ideia to reload page are for clean input fields or reload the feed. But thanks for the advice. I will try another way to reload the content. :)

Comment: @user2711443 sure thing! if you want more help on it I'll be more than happy to provide more guidance. just ask away :)

Comment: There are some legitimate reasons where you would want to reload the page in a SPA. For example when you have a feature that allows users to switch to a different account. IMHO it's better to set the context for the new user and just reload instead of putting the logic all around the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href` to get the current URL. Then you can do your comparison.